# STL array templated class not found

Tags: arrays, stl

i have to compile libcvd ("libCVD is a very portable and high performance C++ library for computer vision, image, and video processing"), including the file cvdimage.cxx.

The problem is that it has the following line:

```
#include <array>
```

and uses this array templated class that should be a simple fixed-length array.

My Visual C++ 2008 edition can't find the array file in the include directory.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you compiling in C++0x/C++11 mode (not sure how VC calls this)? Otherwise `array` is `tr1/array`

Comment: I don't know. How can i check this? Btw, there isn't a tr1 directory under the main include dir...

Answer (score 2):

[`<array>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb981974.aspx) is a TR1 header. For VC++ 2008 you need to get the [Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6922) to have access to those libraries. Note that even if you've already got the Feature Pack, Microsoft say this:

> If you install the Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack and then install the Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, some of the files in the Feature Pack are overwritten and lose the additions made by the Feature Pack.
>
> Please install the Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5 first and then the Feature Pack. If you have already installed the Feature Pack first and then Windows SDK, repairing your VS 2008 installation should solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, at this page http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11310 (Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008) it is suggested to install this: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3138 (Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1). What to do?

Comment: Install the `SP1` like it says, and then install the Feature Pack after that.